# Maven + Tycho adds all workspace enabled plugins to build

Tags: eclipse, plugins, maven-2, tycho

how to declare which `Eclipse workspace plugins` are added to the build?
All Target Platforms are clean and correct and i can't find a way to declare which plugins should be packed and which shouldn't.

It makes no difference if i deselect some plugins in the content-pane of the `Targetplatform`.

thank you!

Comment: Eclipse workspace plugins = RCP plugins? which traget platforms? question is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the following after longer research:

[WARNING] De-selecting bundles in a target definition file is not supported

The Eclipse Target Editor has the possibiltiy to remove individual bundles from the resolved target definition content. (This is done via the selection on the Content tab of the editor, and results in a  tag in the target definition file.) This configuration is currently ignored Tycho (cf. bug 373776).

As an alternative, you can use target platform filters to remove bundles from the target platform.

source: 
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho_Messages_Explained#Target_File_Include_Bundles